# Apply regular expressions on a specific column in Pandas

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset with columns tweetID, tweet-text, RegExp1, RegExp2, RegExp3, RegExp4 and a list of 4 regular expressions. 
I want to apply regular expressions one by one on tweet-text column, if tweet-text satisfy the regular expression then I want to set value to 1 in corresponding RegExp column, and if it does not satisfy then I want to set it to 0.

For example, suppose tweet-text satisfy regular expression number 1 then I want to set corresponding RegExp1 columns's value to 1, and does not satisfy regular expression 2 then I want to set corresponding RegExp2 column's value to 0 and so on. I tried the code given at the end, but it didn't worked for me.

My dataset look like

```
tweetID | tweet-text         | RegExp1 | RexExp2 | RegExp3 | RexExp4
---------------------------------------------------------------------
10001   | to get it or?      |         |         |         |
10333   | I just wonder :)   |         |         |         |
10933   | is it possible dude|         |         |         |
14633   | he is good at      |         |         |         |
```

code:

```
 `regexes = [
    re.compile('i asked .* said'),
    re.compile('you asked me what .*'),
    re.compile('(to get|to see|to look|is it true|is it possible) .*'),
    re.compile('I .* wonder .*')
]
for regex, i in zip(regexes, range(4)):
    columnName = "RegExp"+str(i+1)
    for row in df['tweet-text']:
      if(regex.search(row) != None):
        df[columnName] = 1
      else:
        df[columnName] = 0`
```

(use of pandas will be preferred)thanks

Comment: So where exactly is the difficulty? Did you try writing a code for it?

Comment: I tried many times...but didn't work out.. - @HarshithThota

Comment: So, if you can post the code which you've tried, we can help you figure it out.

Comment: Okay, so where is your dataset? What is your regex? How do you expect any help without helping us understand what you want to do?

Comment: @Irfanullah 1. Details shouldn't go in the comments. 2. We'll need a look at your dataset too. Either a csv or a clipboard paste of your pandas frame.

Comment: @Irfanullah, I hope you found the answer. For future posts, you might have more success if you can make it easy for people to replicate, e.g. if they can copy your data & code to run on their machine with minimal friction. To speed up getting a result, perhaps considering explaining what you've tried and any errors you see. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str.contains` inside a loop. You'll need to pass the regex pattern (not a compiled regex object).

This is what I'm starting with:

```
In [1062]: df.head()
Out[1062]: 
   tweetID            tweet-text    RegExp1    RegExp2    RegExp3 RegExp4
0    10001   to get it or?                                               
1    10333   I just wonder :)                                            
2    10933   is it possible dude                                         
3    14633   he is good at 

In [1063]: regexes = [
      ...:     'i asked .* said',
      ...:     'you asked me what .*',
      ...:     '(?:to get|to see|to look|is it true|is it possible) .*',
      ...:     'I .* wonder .*'
      ...: ]
```

Next, run a loop for each regex pattern. Call `str.contains` and assign the result to each column in turn:

```
In [1090]: for i, r in enumerate(regexes):
      ...:     df['RegExp%d' %(i + 1)] = df['tweet-text'].str.contains(r).astype(int)
      ...:     

In [1091]: df.head()
Out[1091]: 
   tweetID            tweet-text  RegExp1  RegExp2  RegExp3  RegExp4
0    10001   to get it or?              0        0        1        0
1    10333   I just wonder :)           0        0        0        1
2    10933   is it possible dude        0        0        1        0
3    14633   he is good at              0        0        0        0
```

Comment: Thanks..it partially worked .Now problem is that I have to perform searching with ignoring case and multi-line in regular expressions, for which I need to pass compiled regex objects i.e.,  `re.compile('I .* wonder .*', re.I | re.M )` any help?   @ COLDSPEED

Comment: @Irfanullah Take a look at the docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html

Comment: There is a "flags" argument to pass regex flags. You may use that.